# Excel 2016 pull down formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to pull down an average of 6 numbers in a formula that is linked to another spread sheet in the same workbook,=AVERAGE(Daily!B32:B37) when I pull this formula down, I would like to get this formula to read =AVERAGE(Daily!B38:B43) but I only get this =AVERAGE(Daily!B33:B38)  Suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a link to some sample data? It will help with answering this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a string that describes your range and then use INDIRECT() to convert it to a true range reference.

This formula:

```
 =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("Daily!B"&32+6*(ROW()-32)&":B"&37+6*(ROW()-32)))
```

Gives the following result when filled down from C32.

[image]

The portion inside the INDIRECT() function produces the string "Daily!B32:B37" in row 32, and increments the row numbers by 6 for every row after that.

The INDIRECT() function converts the text string into an actual range that AVERAGE() can use.

To put this formula in a different row, change the two "-32"'s to the row number that you're putting it in.